# How to add a number in the file name sequential using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, file, sequence

I would like to add a sequence number in the file name. I tried to create the file, but I still can not figure out how to add the sequence number in the file name.
Here are my code:

```
$Seq_0 = @("AE", "PR")
$Seq_1 = @("A1", "AP", "AS", "E1")
$Seq_2 = @("E2", "JP" , "M1")
$Seq_3 = @("M2", "N1")

$PathPOFiles = ".\PO"
$BID = "00YYR3TT101"
$PathHome = "D:\Folder"
$PathOriJob = ".\Job"
$JobType = "XY"
$Prefix = "AB"

if (Test-Path -Path "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*")
{   
     Get-ChildItem -Path "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*" | ForEach-Object {

          $GetPO = Get-childItem -Path "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*"
     }
     

     # Create job content
     $POfile = Get-ChildItem -Name "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*"
     $POContent = Get-Content -path "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*"
     
     $GetCRM = $POContent | Where-Object {$_ -like "*;CRM*"}
     $CRM = $GetCRM.Substring(5,2)
     $CRM = $CRM.split()

     $POCountry = Get-ChildItem -Name "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*" -File
     $GetCountry = $POCountry.Substring(15,3)
     $GetCountry = $GetCountry.split()
     
     for ( $i = 0; $i -clt $POfile.Count; $i++) {
          if ($POfile.Count -le 1)
          {
               $po = $POfile
          } 
          else {
                                   
               $po = $POfile[$i]
          }

          $xmlcrm = $CRM[$i]
          $xmlcountry = $GetCountry[$i]
          $JobCreatedTime = Get-Date
          
          # Set The Formatting
          $xmlsettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
          $xmlsettings.Indent = $true
          $xmlsettings.IndentChars = "`t"

          $XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("$PathHome\$PathOriJob\$JobType`_$Prefix$BID`_$xmlcrm.job", $xmlsettings)
          $xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
          
          $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Job")
          
          $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Auto")

               $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PO","$po")
               $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

          $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Build")
               $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("BID","$BID")
               $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Prefix","$Prefix")
               $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("CRM","$xmlcrm")
               $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Country","$xmlcountry")
               $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

          $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

          $xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
          $xmlWriter.Flush()
          $xmlWriter.Close()
     }  
     
     $Message = "Creating Job Successfully"
     Write-Host $Message
}
else {
     
     $Message = "File Not Found"
     Write-Host $Message
}
```

from this code, I can generate a file with this format : XY_AB00YYR3TT101_A1.job . The total of the the file depend on the file of this `$POfile = Get-ChildItem -Name "$PathPOFiles\*$BID*"` .
My expectation, I can name the file consider to the sequence I have. If the `$xmlcrm` equal to `$Seq_0` list, then the file will name as XY_AB00YYR3TT101_AE_0.job . if the `$xmlcrm` equal to `$Seq_1` then named by adding `1` . If the `$xmlcrm` does not match to any sequence list, then the file will name by adding `4` as the default.

Anyone can help me please. Really Appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Where does `$Seq_0[1]`, `$Seq_1[1]` etc come into the picture? Basically, are you trying to match `$xmlcrm` to the first object in each $Seq-array (`$Seq_0[0]`) or all objects of each array?

Comment: Can you show sample contents of a file?